# Эльбские песчаниковые горы или Эльбские Песчаниковые горы?

Tags: названия

Название гор: Эльбские песчаниковые горы.... Вот имя собственное, но песчаник - то, из чего они сделаны.Стоит ли материал писать с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Название таково: *Эльбские Песчаниковые горы*. Так сложилось в русском языке.
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Эльбские_Песчаниковые_горы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/153882/Эльбские](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/153882/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Если бы в названиях гор "песчаниковые горы" встречалось бы часто, то, скорее всего, сложилось бы по-другому, но Гугл только это название выдаёт. То есть всё дело в уникальности.